# Bipolar calculations with unkown resistor values and unknown current values

Tags: voltage, transistors, bipolar

Having a hard time figuring out the current and resistor values across resistor Rf and Rc in an NPN germanium transistor. How do I calulate the current across the collector of the transistor with these unknown values? VCC is 12V branching off into Rf and Rb on left side. Rf voltage drop=10.8V. Rb resistor value is 100ohms, 1.2 v, and 12mA. Right side is Rc and Re and the NPN transistor. Rc voltage drop=4. Re resistor value 470ohms, .9V, and 1.91mA.
**Known values:** (Irb=12mA) (Ie=1.91mA) (Erb=1.2V) (Ec=8V) (Erc=4V) (ERf=10.8V) (Ee-c=7.10V)
**Unknown values:** (Ib) (Ic) (Rf) (betadc) (IRf)[image: picture if for reference on how circuit is set up]

Comment: Convert the resistor divider at the BJT case into its Thevenin equivalent. Now you have one less resistor to worry about. Now apply KVL from this Thevenin source, through the BE junction and via the emitter resistor to ground. Assume, at first, that the BJT is in active mode and that a minimum reasonable \$\beta\$ can be applied. Then compute the collector current, multiply it by the collector resistor, and see if that voltage drop can be sustained, or not. If not, then the BJT is saturated and the \$\beta\$ and active mode assumption is false.

Comment: Wow, a germanium transistor problem!  It's always interesting when questions involving old germanium parts show up here.  (Of course the same exact principles in this question apply to silicon, but this must be an old test/text.)  Vacuum tube (valve) questions are even more interesting. :)